# How would I return a View conforming to a protocol from SwiftUI View body?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've tried this

```
protocol ErrorableViewProtocol: View {
    var error: Error? { get set }
}

struct ErrorableView: View {
    var normal: any ErrorableViewProtocol
    var error: Error
    
    var body: some View {
        if let error = normal.error {
            ErrorView(error: error)
        } else {
            normal
        }
    }
}
```

but my knowledge of swift is lacking resulting in:

[image]

Please advice what's a good way to show an ErrorView in place or navigate to that once a network error has happened. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to make your View generic:

```
struct ErrorableView<T: ErrorableViewProtocol>: View {
    var normal: T
    var error: Error
    
    var body: some View {
        if let error = normal.error {
            ErrorView(error: error)
        } else {
            normal
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I make ErrorableView track changes to normal.error and rebuild? currently it does not

Comment: @AntonTropashko Take a look at `PreferenceKey`. But I would think this is out of the scope of this question TBH. Better ask a new one.

Comment: Thanks. Looking. The separate question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74181700/why-is-my-code-is-not-reacting-to-changes-to-a-published-property