# Why is my code is not reacting to changes to a @Published property

Tags: swiftui

```
protocol ErrorableViewProtocol: View {
    var error: Error? { get set }
}

class ObservableError: ObservableObject {
    @Published var error: Error?
}

struct ErrorableView<T: ErrorableViewProtocol>: View {
    var errorable: T
    
    var body: some View {
        if let error = errorable.error {
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ how would I change this to have ErrorableView react to changes to this property and rebuild ErrorableView? usage is below
            ErrorView(error: error)
        } else {
            errorable
        }
    }
}
```

here is the usage

```
struct SearchMediaView: View, ErrorableViewProtocol {
    @StateObject var observable_error: ObservableError = ObservableError()
    @State var errorAccessAllowed = false // to dodge the stupid warning
    var error: Error? {
        get {
            if !errorAccessAllowed {
                return nil
            }
            return observable_error.error
        }
        set {
            observable_error.error = newValue
        }
    }
  ...
```

Looks like this is not supported https://forums.swift.org/t/property-wrapper-requirements-in-protocols/33953

Could I at least somehow marry body to kvo if I can't switch on an observable property???

Answer (score -1):

Had to use PreferenceKey to push the state change between the views